# Pandas : OR If value contains "-" then do

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code (translated):

```
m1 = df['stock']>=1
m2 = (df['stock']==0) & (df['date'].notna())
df['deliverytime'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['2-4 days', df['date']], 'unknown')
```

So that means: when stock is above 0 (1), then get 2-4 days, otherwise, check the date, and if stock is for example 0, and there is no date, then there will be 'unknown'.

Now the following; the supplier has also added negative stock values, example: -10, -5 etc.

I would like to modify "m2", so that it says: stock = 0, stock has "-" sign, and date is not empty THEN do..

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

-- edit - simple dataframe --

```
stock,date
2,9-9-2019
-4,9-9-2019
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the dataframe or few lines of dataframe to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 2 lines of code to replace an negative value to 0, it's an different approach, but it works!

The 2 lines are:

```
num = df._get_numeric_data()
num[num < 0] = 0
```

Thanks for repleying and checking all!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change `==` to `<=` and `&` to `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m2 = (df['stock']<=0) | (df['date'].notna())
```

Comment: Good catch by the way +1.

Comment: thanks for your comment, though the "<=0" doesn't work. Also for the date it hasn't to be an OR, but an AND, beceause the date doesn't need to be empty for m2.

Comment: What do you mean with df check?